# Where to declare javascript/jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to do some stuff with jquery/js (I don't know which one it is..), for example this script ; http://pastebin.com/V3HpU0NY - > http://blog.mainstreethost.com/light-youtube-embeds-faster-page-load#.VG9HKamkVSJ

But now comes the difficult part.

Url: http://erwin.my89.nl/stage/sieh/

[image]
This is the website when you go to the url.

This loads the "gallery (top)" and all content/ and kinda images(lazyload) for all the 'gallery' posts. If this has to be done another way please say so.

When you click a image you'll get this:
[image]

I hope you understand the idea.

So everything working ok

but now i go in to the inspector and i encounter this?!

[image]

I assume it is because i have the script defined in the loop of the content.. so when i click a gallery image, it loads another bunch of those text/css's.

So my question is: Is this the right way to do it? or should i be doing this different?

```
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post($post->ID);
 if ($metas) {
      foreach ($metas as $metakey) {

        } elseif ($metakey['url']) {
            preg_match(
                '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
                $metakey['url'],
                $matches
            );
            $id = $matches[1];

            ?>
            <div class="youtube" id="<?php echo $id ?>" style="width: 560px; height: 315px;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/youtube.js"></script>

        <?php
```

^part of the code, if need more please say so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your CSS file/s in the head? That's where it normally goes.

Also, I don't see anywhere in your PHP where it could be loading these `<style></style>` tags. However it does look like it's going to import the same script at the end of each loop.

Could you provide more information on what your exact problem is?

Comment: The scripts are getting loaded in this part <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/youtube.js"></script>

/js/youtube.js has that code look here http://pastebin.com/V3HpU0NY

the problem is that it gets definied so often, i dont think its supposed to.

Comment: Have you tried placing that <script> tag above the while loop?

Comment: Yeah, script stops working. Think it has to do something with that the content gets loaded on a click, and that the script doesnt come along